# How to set wifi security options in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, security

I need to set up WiFi connection on my Ubuntu computer. It requires to fill security options in the window: 
[image]

I don't know how to fill the form. However, I have a Windows computer, that connected to the same Wi-Fi. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to obtain these parameters from the windows connection. How can I find out actual values for security tab in Wi-Fi connection?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find out actual values for security tab in Wi-Fi connection?

Check your router. All the information you need will be there and the log in there will also tell you why you can not connect.

> However, I have a Windows computer, that connected to the same Wi-Fi.

We are not windows experts but I do not understand why you have issues if that is the case. Windows also tells you how the connection is set up in the network settings (that is in the popup you get from "properties" on the network icon for your card).